# .innerHTML not changing value on maths quiz

Tags: javascript, html, css

As part of a school project I have to make a full randomised maths quiz (with three operators) using HTML, CSS, Javascript and JQuery, if necessairy. It also has to include css styling i.e. it has to look good as well.

I've hit a road block where my question doesn't appear in the assigned div of 'questions'. I understand I've made plenty of mistakes, this is my first time using javascript, any help would be appriciated and if you need the full code, just ask. Thanks.

```
function getNumber(){
    var oplist = ["=","-","*"];
    num1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
    num2 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
    op = oplist [Math.floor(Math.random()* oplist.length)];
    if (op == "+"){
        ans = (num1 + num2)
    }
    else if (op == "-"){
        ans = (num1 - num2)
    }
    else if (op == "*"){
        ans = (num1 * num2)
    }
}

document.getElementById("questions").innerHTML = num1 + op + num2;
```

Comment: you never call `getNumber` anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply inside the function `return  num1 + op + num2+'='+ans;`

```js
var num1,num2,op
var ans =0;
function getNumber(){
    var oplist = ["=","-","*"];
    num1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
    num2 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
    op = oplist [Math.floor(Math.random()* oplist.length)];
    if (op == "+"){
        ans = (num1 + num2)
    }
    else if (op == "-"){
        ans = (num1 - num2)
    }
    else if (op == "*"){
        ans = (num1 * num2)
    }
    return  num1 + op + num2+'='+ans;
}

document.getElementById("questions").innerHTML = getNumber();
```

```html
<p id="questions"></p>
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked! Will definately come back here in future ventures.

Comment: welcome ...@J.Doe .dont forget to mark as a answer.It help full for future visitors

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"
            integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE="
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="questions"></div>
    <div>
        <input type="button" onclick="getNumber()" />
    </div>
</body>
</html>

<script>

        function getNumber() {
            var oplist = ["=", "-", "*"];
            num1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
            num2 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
            op = oplist[Math.floor(Math.random() * oplist.length)];
            if (op == "+") {
                ans = (num1 + num2)
            }
            else if (op == "-") {
                ans = (num1 - num2)
            }
            else if (op == "*") {
                ans = (num1 * num2)
            }

            document.getElementById("questions").innerHTML = num1 + op + num2;
        }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling your function

**document.getElementById("questions").innerHTML = getNumber();**

```js
function getNumber(){
    var oplist = ["=","-","*"],
    num1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1),
    num2 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1),
    op = oplist [Math.floor(Math.random()* oplist.length)],
ans = 0;
    if (op == "+"){
        ans = (num1 + num2)
    }
    else if (op == "-"){
        ans = (num1 - num2)
    }
    else if (op == "*"){
        ans = (num1 * num2)
    }
return ans;
}

document.getElementById("questions").innerHTML = getNumber();
```

```html
<div id="questions"></div>
```

Comment: You return nothing. `return num1 + op + num2;`.

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't do anything, got any other ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your Code should be something like this.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="questions"></div>
    <div>
        <input type="button" onclick="getNumber()" value="Get Answer"/>
    </div>
<script>

        function getNumber() {
            var oplist = ["=", "-", "*"];
            num1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
            num2 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
            op = oplist[Math.floor(Math.random() * oplist.length)];
            if (op == "+") {
                ans = (num1 + num2)
            }
            else if (op == "-") {
                ans = (num1 - num2)
            }
            else if (op == "*") {
                ans = (num1 * num2)
            }

            document.getElementById("questions").innerHTML = num1 + op + num2;
        }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```